# Name for a street that goes through the green area

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I am looking for a word for this type of road: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQlkA.jpg

Some sort of alley that goes through the lawn and surrounded by trees all the way along it, through which transport can move (not specifically trams).

On the picture, you could see that the rails are located in between of two roads, but that's not important. The accent is made upon the green path, which could be a separate road as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avenue / allee ([wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avenue_(landscape)))

> **In landscaping, an avenue, or allée, is traditionally a straight path or road with a line of trees or large shrubs running along each side**, which is used, as its French source venir ("to come") indicates, to emphasize the "coming to," or arrival at a landscape or architectural feature. In most cases, the trees planted in an avenue will be all of the same species or cultivar, so as to give uniform appearance along the full length of the avenue. The French term allée is used for avenues planted in parks and landscape gardens, as well as boulevards such as the Grande Allée in Quebec City, Canada, Bologna Alley in Zagreb and Karl-Marx-Allee in Berlin.

Comment: You are great, @0xFEE1DEAD Thank you!